# Is this a bug of MySQL? Two tables are Cascaded On Delete. When parent is deleted, child's AFTER DELETE is not triggered

Tags: mysql, triggers, cascade, relation

I have two tables, assuming one is called `parent_table`, the other is `child_table`. Their relation is set as CASCADE ON DELETE (by Primary Key and Foreign Key).

And `child_table` has an archive table called `child_history_table`. I wrote an INSERT sentence in its AFTER DELETE trigger to insert the deleted record to `child_history_table`.

Now the problem is: if I delete a record of `parent_table`, of course the related record in `child_table` will be automatically deleted. But its AFTER DELETE trigger seems not invoked. Because no record was inserted into the history table.

Whereas if I delete a record of `child_table` manually, its AFTER DELETE trigger will work normally, and a record was inserted into the history table.

How can I solve this problem? Is the only way to set the relation to NO ACTION ON DELETE, and manually delete the child's records by writing codes in the parent's DELETE trigger?

Comment: "Cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers." ([docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html)). I'd write a BEFORE DELETE trigger for the parent table.

Comment: Thank you so much for your so prompt reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation:

> [13.1.18.6 Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):
>
> ...
>
> **Note**
>
> Cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers.
>
> ...

Comment: Thank you so much for your so prompt reply!